# Unlock feature after buying from website in iOS app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, unlock

I have a question on in app purchase
I have a requirement like user can get the premium account from in app purchase in the app to extend usage of the the existing functionality. The same feature can be brought from the website by logging into his account in web. If user buys the product from web and does login in the iPhone app, are we suppose to unlock this feature in iPhone? Apple doesn't say abut these kind of flows in their docs.

Since the premium account is a subscription based product like purhasing for 1 month or 1 year and not auto renewal. User has to buy the premium service once it expires.

So is my server has to maintain status like is logged in user is premium user or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what the content is - in the [guidelines doc](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) - look at 11.14. Approved content is OK if pruchased outside the app (magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, video and cloud storage) and you can purchase this content inside the app (apple will take their cut)

What you can't do is link to a website to purchase

Check out Apps like Kindle and Comixology

Comment: Basically my premium service allows user to do broadcast for 60 seconds if user buys this. By default it will be given 20 seconds for user to record audio and broadcast to channel. By using premium service user can cast a audio of length 1 minute. Since it is a non renewable subscription, a user can buy this same from website also. At that point should I allow user in the app to use the premium service?

Comment: No - read section 11 of the guidelines. It's pretty clear that they don't want you unlocking functionality through purchases away from the app - read section 11.1 and 11.2

Comment: Joe Booth : Yes the points 11.1 and 11.2 clearly states that you cannot provide service in the app if is brought from outside the app.